# MongoDB Unique Index issue in array of subdocuments

Tags: arrays, mongodb, unique-index

I have a document like this:

```
{
   _id : ObjectID(),
   title: "",
   items: [
      {
         "itemId" : 1234678,
      }
   ]
}
```

itemId is a unique index created like this:

```
db.allItems.createIndex( { "items.itemId" : 1 }, { unique: true});
```

And then everything works fine, until I set items array (not pushing one), in this case, unique index does not work. The following data in the update operation (using `$set`) does not throw an error and works fine, which MUST NOT. I mean it creates the sub-document  without any unique error

```
items: [
  {
    itemId: 1234678
  },
  {
    itemId: 1234678
  }
]
```

While I expect MongoDB to throw error that `itemId` is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDb index uniqueness is applicable for documents, not for nested arrays.

If you try to insert new document with:

```
items: [
  {
     "itemId" : 1234678,
  },
  ...
]
```

MonogDB will throw `E11000 duplicate key error collection`

Comment: is it related to `$set` or it generally ignores it?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi it generally ignores